# What is the purpose of the iop statement and can I get the same output without it?

Tags: asp.net, vbscript

I have a following function written in vbscript that I am trying to understand and port. I am not sure why the statements `iop = iop - 100` and `iop = iop + 100` are required. Can I remove those and get the same output? `iop` is not used anywhere else.

```
function IsMobile(byref op)
    IsMobile = false
    if op <> empty then
        if InStr(1, op, ",") < 1 then

            on error resume next
            Dim iop
            iop = CLng(op)
            if err then
                err.Clear
                exit function
            end if
            on error goto 0

            if iop >= 100 and iop < 200 then
                iop = iop - 100
                IsMobile = true
            elseif iop <= -100 and iop > -200 then
                iop = iop + 100
                IsMobile = true
            elseif iop = 3 or iop = -3 then
                IsMobile = IsMobileBrowser()
            end if
        end if
    end if
end function
```

So can I write the above as snippet as

```
if iop >= 100 and iop < 200 then
    IsMobile = true
elseif iop <= -100 and iop > -200 then
    IsMobile = true
elseif iop = 3 or iop = -3 then
    IsMobile = IsMobileBrowser()
end if
```

I am a vbscript/asp newbie. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently they are not required anymore. As you thought, it's safe to remove all those `iop` assignments except the first one.